# Session ID changes in each Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis

I have an asp.net application in which i redirect from one page to another. I'm validating the `SessionID` in the second page to make sure both requests are of the same session. Now, my problem is the SessionID changes whenever a Postback is happened.

Now, I added the Session tag into my `web.config`

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true"/>
```

Now, the problem with the session was solved and a new issue started appearing. Whenever i make a call with `Cookiless="true"` in my `web.config` file, my URL shows a junk address

`http://localhost:10766/(S(ojbcobj0aw0wiosttgpknwby))/registration.aspx`

If I remove the `Cookieless` tag the session will be lost in the next page?
Do anyone know why is this coming and if any fix is there for this problem?

---

I went through lot of threads but i couldn't find a proper fix for this.

---

EDITED:
I Set my `cookieless="false"` and now its working fine.

Comment: Seems a problem with using cookie. What browser have you tested? What is the server setup?

Comment: Im just working with VS2013. IE, Chrome and Mozilla i tried. Everywhere im getting the same.

Comment: Most samples explicitly state `cookieless='false'`. Please try that.

Comment: may this link will helps you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597387/asp-net-sessionid-changing-on-postbacks)

Comment: Did you store something in Session? If you didn't, why should the server keep that empty session? See the [highest voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/597405/121309) in the link Chirag gave.

Comment: Cookieless=false worked.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Framework has 05 (five) session state modes:

- **InProc mode**, which stores session state in memory on the Web server. This is the default.
- **StateServer mode**, which stores session state in a separate process called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.
- **SQLServer mode** stores session state in a SQL Server database. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.
- **Custom mode**, which enables you to specify a custom storage provider.
- **Off mode**, which disables session state.

Now i need to know exactly what does your application do to recommend the better solution:

1. Do you store something in Session?
2. Are you using multithreading?
3. How many servers your farm will have (when the application go live)
4. Does your app connect to database?

If you keep your original web.config, by default your application will use InProc mode and will store session id on cookie, unless your browser or local server denied it.

I'm waiting to the answers to complement my post.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.ASPX

Comment: To make it clear: InProc will not store all data in cookies, just the SessionID. The stored data stays on the server.