# SessionID changing at every page call

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, session-variables

I'm accessing the `SessionID` using this code in my class:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
```

however I find that `SessionID` changes at every page postback, this happens in a short time, so the current session should not expire already. I supposed that the `SessionID` to remain the same for the whole time until expired.

Comment: Session is (usually) controlled by the presence of a cookie. If you are not logging in users then there will be a new session on each request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session ID changes in each Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038655/session-id-changes-in-each-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using cookie-based session state, ASP.NET does not allocate
>   storage for session data until the Session object is used. As a
>   result, a new session ID is generated for each page request until the
>   session object is accessed. If your application requires a static
>   session ID for the entire session, you can either implement the
>   Session_Start method in the application's Global.asax file and store
>   data in the Session object to fix the session ID, or you can use code
>   in another part of your application to explicitly store data in the
>   Session object.

like

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Session["init"] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Copied form [Session ID changes in each Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038655/session-id-changes-in-each-request)

Answer (score 1):

You should Use the Session_Start method in the application Global.asax file. Below Link may help you

[ASP.NET: Session.SessionID changes between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874078/asp-net-session-sessionid-changes-between-requests)